# How to Convert PDF to a Dataframe while Preserving the Format

Tags: r, pdf, tidyverse

```
library(pdftools)
library(tidyverse)
```

Using pdftools or another pdf converter package, I would like to convert a PDF to a dataframe while preserving the format which is shown in the first pic below.

I tried to input the structure using dput (not quite sure how to do this correctly) and the contents are at the bottom to reproduce the PDF file.

I imported the PDF file and tried the "pdf_text" function from the PDFtools package but I'm not sure how to work with the output. I'm open to other PDF converting packages as well.

```
pdf<-pdf_text("PDFPractice.pdf")
```

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

"This is a header that I want removed.\r\nI also want this removed.\r\nAnd this too.\r\nProgram           Sem         Code     ID ID2  Name    NameTwp\r\nA103               2       2BX100     345   D   Chris   Newson\r\n                                      367   E   Karen   Everett\r\n                                      567   D   Steve   Mills\r\n                                      432   S   Juan    Lista\r\nThis is a header that I want removed.\r\nI also want this removed.\r\nAnd this too.\r\nProgram           Sem         Code     ID ID2  Name    NameTwp\r\nB101               1       3T3AAA     345  S  James     Lewis\r\n                                      322  D   Jesse   McKenzie\r\n                                      511  T   Yoshie   Abe\r\n                                      478  S    Alfred  Yuan\r\nThis is a header that I want removed.\r\nI also want this removed.\r\nAnd this too.\r\n"

Comment: Two `library()` calls do not qualify as "showing a code attempt and identify what wasn't working". We don't have the PDF nor do we have any `dput()` of your attempt(s) at reading it in with `pdftools`. Without knowing the structure you're ending up with it's unlikely folks will be able to intuit a solution for you.

Comment: How do I attach the PDF?

Comment: Googling something like "extract table data from pdf" is probably going to be more productive than asking on here, I'm not sure that `pdftools` is particularly suited to this task and the question is too broad to be a good SO question.

Comment: you point to it somewhere (not ideal) like gdocs or dropbox. it'd be better if you showed the pdftools import code and a dput of the resultant structure for at least one page.  There are examples of this out on the intertubes tho. Like: https://rud.is/b/2017/04/13/come-fly-with-me-well-not-really-comparing-involuntary-disembarking-rates-across-u-s-airlines-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(magick)

################################################
#### Step 1 : We convert the image to a PDF ####
################################################

path_PDF <- "C:\\temp.pdf"
path_PNG <- "C:\\vH68S.png"
path_Word <- "C:\\temp.docx"

pdf(path_PDF, height = 11.5, width = 8.5)
im <- image_read(path_PNG)
plot(im)
abline(h = -10, col = "black")
abline(h = 45, col = "black")
abline(h = 85, col = "black")
abline(h = 140, col = "black")
abline(h = 185, col = "black")
abline(h = 300, col = "black")
abline(h = 340, col = "black")
abline(h = 390, col = "black")
abline(h = 440, col = "black")
abline(h = 490, col = "black")
abline(h = 540, col = "black")
abline(h = 625, col = "black")
abline(v = 100, col = "black")
abline(v = 230, col = "black")
abline(v = 330, col = "black")
abline(v = 450, col = "black")
abline(v = 600, col = "black")
abline(v = 700, col = "black")
abline(v = 800, col = "black")
abline(v = 1000, col = "black")
dev.off()

####################################################################
#### Step 2 : We use the OCR of Word to convert the PDF to word ####
####################################################################
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_PDF),
                                   ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

doc$SaveAs2(path_Word)

####################################
#### Step 3 : We read the table ####
####################################
nb_Table <- doc$tables()$count()
list_Table <- list()

for(l in 1 : nb_Table)
{
  nb_Row <- doc$tables(l)$Rows()$Count()
  nb_Col <- doc$tables(l)$Columns()$Count()
  mat_Temp <- matrix(NA, nrow = nb_Row, ncol = nb_Col)
  
  for(i in 1 : nb_Row)
  {
    for(j in 1 : nb_Col)
    {
      mat_Temp[i, j] <- tryCatch(doc$tables(l)$cell(i, j)$range()$text(), error = function(e) NA)
    }
  }
  
  list_Table[[l]] <- mat_Temp
}

list_Table

[[1]]
      [,1]   [,2]                                               [,3]                      
 [1,] "\r\a" "This is a hea \rI also want t \rAnd this too\r\a" "er that I is remove\r\a" 
 [2,] "\r\a" "Program\r\a"                                      "Sem\r\a"                 
 [3,] "\r\a" "A103\r\a"                                         "2\r\a"                   
 [4,] "\r\a" "\r\a"                                             "\r\a"                    
 [5,] "\r\a" "\r\a"                                             "\r\a"                    
 [6,] "\r\a" "\r\a"                                             "\r\a"                    
 [7,] "\r\a" "\r\a"                                             "\r\a"                    
 [8,] "\r\a" "This is a hea \rI also want t \rAnd this too\r\a" "er that I is remove \r\a"
 [9,] "\r\a" "Program\r\a"                                      "Sem\r\a"                 
[10,] "\r\a" "BIOI\r\a"                                         "1\r\a"                   
[11,] "\r\a" "\r\a"                                             "\r\a"                    
[12,] "\r\a" "\r\a"                                             "\r\a"                    
[13,] "\r\a" "\r\a"                                             "\r\a"                    
      [,4]                [,5]      [,6]      [,7]         [,8]          
 [1,] "nt removed\r\a"    "\r\a"    "\r\a"    "\r\a"       "\r\a"        
 [2,] "Code\r\a"          "ID\r\a"  "ID2\r\a" "Name\r\a"   "NameTwp\r\a" 
 [3,] "2BXIOO\r\a"        "345\r\a" "D\r\a"   "Chris\r\a"  "Newson\r\a"  
 [4,] "\r\a"              "367\r\a" "\r\a"    "Karen\r\a"  "Everett\r\a" 
 [5,] "\r\a"              "567\r\a" "D\r\a"   "Steve\r\a"  "Mills\r\a"   
 [6,] "\r\a"              "432\r\a" "s\r\a"   "Juan\r\a"   "Lista\r\a"   
 [7,] "\r\a"              "\r\a"    "\r\a"    "\r\a"       "\r\a"        
 [8,] "nt removed\r.\r\a" "\r\a"    "\r\a"    "\r\a"       "\r\a"        
 [9,] "Code\r\a"          "ID\r\a"  "ID2\r\a" "Name\r\a"   "NameTwp\r\a" 
[10,] "3T3AAA\r\a"        "345\r\a" "s\r\a"   "James\r\a"  "Lewis\r\a"   
[11,] "\r\a"              "322\r\a" "D\r\a"   "Jesse\r\a"  "McKenzie\r\a"
[12,] "\r\a"              "511\r\a" "\r\a"    "Yoshie\r\a" "\r\a"        
[13,] "\r\a"              "\r\a"    "\r\a"    "\r\a"       "\r\a"
```